# Async function Uncaught (in promise) undefined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do some validations before creating/updating an entry as shown below:

```
async save(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        if(!this.isCampaignValid){
          this.handleError()
          reject()
        }
        else{
          this.$store
            .dispatch('updateCampaign')
            .then((res)=>{
              resolve()
              this.showNotification(res.message, 'success')
            })
            .catch(error=>{
              this.showNotification(error.message, 'error')
              reject()
            })
        }
      })
    },
```

the `isCampaignValid` is a computed value which computes the validity.

If the campaign is not valid, then I'm getting an error in the console as below:

> Uncaught (in promise) undefined

The `this.handleError()` function works too. How can handle this promise error situation?

Comment: It sounds like it's in your `isCampaignValid`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case handleError() throws, try:

```
if (!this.isCampaignValid) {
  try {
    this.handleError()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  reject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to return a promise in an `async` function. It implicitly returns one, resolving with the value returned by the function or rejecting with the error object if the function throws. Although you *could* return a promise and JS unpacks it for you, it's unneeded code.

That said, because `async` returns a promise, you'll have to *catch* that promise too. Since your first conditional block just throws an error but doesn't catch it, the promise returned by `save` will reject. You need to handle that rejection.

Here's a simplified version of your code to see where it's happening.

```
async save(){
    if(!this.isCampaignValid){
      this.handleError()
      // Throwing an error in an async function is equivalent to a reject.
      throw new Error('Campaign is not valid') // Here
    }
    else{
      try {
        const res = await this.$store.dispatch('updateCampaign')
        this.showNotification(res.message, 'success')
      } catch (e) {
        this.showNotification(error.message, 'error')
      }
    }
},

// When you call save, catch the error
yourObject.save()
  .then(() => {...})
  .catch(() => {...})

// If your call is in an async function, you can try-catch as well
try {
  await yourObject.save()
} catch(e) {
  // It failed.
}
```